# Bitbucket Cloud repository using Repository Access Token for Databricks Service Principal git credentials

Tags: git, databricks, credentials, bitbucket-cloud, service-principal

I am trying to get a Databricks Workflow running as a Service Principal. I am using a Bitbucket Cloud Repository Access Token so that the git credentials for the Databricks Service Principal to use are not tied to an individual user.

Based on the [Databricks API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/gitcredentials/create) to create git credentials, it's not clear how a Repository Access Token should fit given there is no defined `git_username` other than the `<hash>@bots.bitbucket.org` ID which does not work. (It works fine for Personal Access Tokens given the username is well documented).

I tried various variations of the git user.name Bitbucket gives me as part of the Repository Access Token.

I expect the correct magical combination of `git_username` and `personal_access_token` passed to the Databricks API to authenticate successfully. Unfortunately it's [not documented](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/gitcredentials/create).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have two issues here:

- Using Bitbucket [Repository Access Tokens](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/using-access-tokens/)
- Using a **Service Principal** in Databricks

##### Bitbucket Repository Access Tokens

I am assuming that you are using **Bitbucket Cloud**.

Bitbucket **Repository Access Tokens** are a good way to give Bitbucket access to a 'bot' account such as CI/CD or, in your case, to an automated workflow running in another system. The generated Token is associated with the Repository rather than a human, so if a person leaves your organisation the Token will continue to work.

When a Token is generated, Bitbucket provides various forms of how to use it. Take a close look at this one:

> **How to use this token with your Git repository**
>
> To clone this repository using this token, run:
>
> `git clone https://x-token-auth:<long-token-here>@bitbucket.org/company/repository.git`

It isn't totally clear, but it is saying that **the username is `x-token-auth`** and the password is the long token provided. **This is very important!!**

##### Databricks Service Principal

Setting git credentials on a Service Principal isn't easy. You'll need to use `curl` or Postman to generate the configuration. (Why don't they put it in the UI, I have no idea!)

The steps are:

- Create the **Service Principal** in the Databricks UI
- Generate a **Personal Access Token for the Service Principal** by using your own Personal Access Token and a `on-behalf-of` call (instructions an be found on [Service principals for Databricks automation | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/service-principals.html))
- Use the returned Access Token to **store git credentials against the Service Principal:**

From [Service principals for CI/CD | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-sp.html):

```bash
curl -X POST \
${DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/git-credentials \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <service-principal-access-token>' \
--data @set-git-credentials.json \
| jq .
```

The important part comes in the `json` configuration file:

```
set-git-credentials.json:

{
   "personal_access_token": "<Git Provider Access Token>",
   "git_username": "x-token-auth",
   "git_provider": "bitbucketCloud"
}
```

Notice how `git_username` uses `x-token-auth` that was mentioned by Bitbucket earlier? This is the most important part. Also, make sure the `git_provider` is set to `bitbucketCloud`.

As a side note, if you get it wrong, the process for **deleting the git credentials is quite painful**. You need to obtain the  *ID* that was associated with the git credentials. It is displayed after using the above `git-credentials` command, which returns with something like:

```json
{
  "credential_id": 749722601042,
  "git_provider": "bitbucketCloud",
  "git_username": "x-token-auth"
}
```

You can then use that `credential_id` with the [Delete a credential | REST API reference | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/gitcredentials/delete) API call to delete the existing credentials and then try to set them again. If you don't remember the `credential_id` you can use [Get Git credentials | REST API reference | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/gitcredentials/list) to retrieve it.

**Bottom line:** Make sure to use `x-token-auth` as the username.

Comment: There's now an easier way to create Tokens On Behalf Of other users using the Databricks CLI: [Provision a service principal for Databricks automation - Databricks UI | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/service-principals.html)